# What forms of "be" are correct in "I prefer that the problem [be] handled at home"?

Tags: grammar, tense

How should I make this sentence?

> 1. I prefer that the problem be handled at home.
> 2. I prefer that the problem is handled at home.
> 3. I prefer the problem to be handled at home.
> 4. I prefer that the problem was handled at home.

Which one is the correct? And what's difference between them?

Comment: Please don't post a sequence of sentences and ask which is correct. You can get better answers by explaining why you think any of them might be right or wrong. You can explain the context that you might want to use these sentences. You can describe what you have done already to answer the question

Answer (score -1):

For starters, number 4 and number 2 are out of the question. The switch between present and past tense just doesn't work in number 4. Grammatically, the first one is most appropriate if you are in conversation with someone, for example if talking to a student's parent you would say "I can't deal with this drama in my classroom. *I prefer that the problem be handled at home.*" The third may work if you rephrased it to say "I *would* prefer the problem to be handled at home."

Comment: Is it wrong to say  2 and 4?

Comment: It depends on the context. If you are looking for the correct one, you would do best to stick with the first one. I would definitely stray away from number 4, number two could work, but I find it hard to think of a scenario I would use it in.

Comment: Doesn't 2 mean the same as 1? Also what would be the most likely sentence out of all of them i would  hear in casual situation? Like if i have a discussion with anyone in my family. PS: do ame speakers use the subjunctive mood? Because i heard they barely use it nowadays

Comment: Number 2 is **not** out of the question in British English.

Comment: I feel like number 2 creates an different emphasis, like you might with a poem or a song lyric.   It makes the handling of the problem the most important part of the sentence.

Comment: The grammatical logic of #1 is inconsistent. You might hear it in real-life English, but it would be inelegant in written English, unless you were quoting a conversation. A standard indicative followed by a subjunctive doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lautde Carfeg: I've been hearing the rumour that subjunctives are dead or dying for several decades now. The fact is you can avoid them if you wish, but lots of people (including me) find them useful in the on-going battle to find the language to say what you mean.  The fact that in form they're often identical to the indicative mood doesn't help their visibility, but they're very much still used, and still useful!

Answer (score -1):

1. I prefer that the problem be handled at home.
   This sentence uses the subjunctive mood (be handled) to express a preference or a hypothetical situation. It is grammatically correct and formal.
2. I prefer the problem to be handled at home.
   This sentence uses an infinitive construction (to be handled) to express preference. It is also grammatically correct and more commonly used in everyday speech.
3. I prefer that the problem is handled at home.
   This sentence is less formal and less grammatically correct compared to sentence 1, as it does not use the subjunctive mood. However, you may still hear it used in casual conversation.
4. I prefer that the problem was handled at home.
   This sentence uses the past tense (was handled), which implies that the speaker wishes the problem had been handled at home in the past. It's grammatically correct in the context of expressing a past preference or regret, but it may not convey the intended meaning if the speaker is talking about a current or future preference.

Comment: On number 1: I'm not sure an indicative main clause can take a subjunctive subordinate clause and still make sense. Any more than the subjunctive in "I like that he be grateful for the help she gave him" makes sense. Imo, the main clause needs to be in a conditional tense.

Answer (score -1):

1. "I prefer [that] the problem be handled at home" has a present tense
   in the subjunctive mood for the subordinate clause and an indicative
   present for the main clause. It's not a mixed conditional that makes any sense. You might hear it in spoken English, but I wouldn't write it down, except where you're quoting someone speaking.
   https://ludwig.guru/s/I+prefer+that+it+be provides only one exact match, albeit from the New York Times, but it's a direct quote from the spoken word, sort of proving the above point.
2. "I prefer the problem to be handled at home" uses an infinitive
   structure. It is perfectly intelligible and elegant, and indicates a
   general rule about my actual preference in relation to the matter at
   hand.
3. With "I prefer [that] the problem is handled at home" the
   subordinate clause is rendered in the present tense in the
   indicative mood, indicating that the (on-going or habitual) problem is in fact generally
   handled at home and that the speaker likes it that way. It's fairly correct, though one might argue you could choose "I'm happy ..." instead of "I prefer ..." without losing much nuance.
4. "I prefer that the problem was handled at home" doesn't make much
   sense in any circumstance I can imagine.  It seems to be an
   indication of a current preference about a past event, which makes
   no more sense than (say) "I prefer that Napoleon lost the Battle of
   Waterloo."  It *could* (I suppose) be interpreted as "I'm happy that the problem was
   handled at home," but it's at best an inelegant and confusing way of
   saying so.

If you use a conditional form in the main clause, then you can use the subjunctive mood (either in the present or in the past) in the subordinate clause.

- "I'd prefer that the problem be handled at home" and
- "I'd prefer that the problem was/were handled at home"

mean basically the same thing, as does:

- "I'd prefer if the problem was/were handled at home."

They all express the speaker's preference about how and where an actual, real-world problem should be dealt with.